# STL files for official Pi Zero case

Tags: case

Is there an 3D model, ideally an STL file, available for the official [Raspberry Pi Zero case](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-case/)?

I'm not looking to print my own case, rather I want to create a mounting clip for it so that I can print a gooseneck mount so that I can position the Pi Zero & camera module.

[image: Raspberry Pi Zero case]

Comment: Thought about using the 3M Command strips designed for hooks, pictures etc?  These can be pulled off when you need.  Details fir the UK versions are https://command.3m.co.uk/3M/en_GB/command-gb/hooks-strips/

Comment: Thanks @Andyroo, I had seen these used on an Adafruit project - I think they could work but I'd still like to be able to print a clip / mount for the case.

Comment: this may help https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4613729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither RPF or RPT have released STL files under the CC licence they detail [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/creative-commons/).

They have given mechanical drawings for most things in the hardware section of the documentation [(here)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/README.md) and you can find the details of the [Zero case](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/rpi_MECH_Zero_case_blank.pdf) and the [camera lid](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/rpi_MECH_Zero_case_camera.pdf) within there (though the lid has no details of the hole placement or size).

As these are injection mouldings, I think you are going to end up looking for 3rd party 3D printed cases rather than the original.  If this is for a child’s room, I would build one from Lego :-)

Comment: Thanks Andy. I did find those drawings before coming to ask my question, but as you say they lack some of the details I'd need. I think as you suggest I'll look for a 3rd party model and use that to build the mounting bracket that I need. It's actually a camera project for a pet mouse! Thanks again

Comment: No probs.  Good luck - at least your is caged - I’m after squirrels and robins at the mo!